# Existence of matrix which satisfies the equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Does there exist a $3\times 3$ real matrix $A$ which satisfies the following equation:
$$ A^2 + A +7I = 0$$
Where $I$ is $3 \times 3 $ unit matrix. I suppose that there doesn't exist such matrix, but i don't now how to find contraddiction.
From this equation we can find eigenvalues. Suppose $Av = \lambda x$, then
$$ (A^2 + A +7I )(v) = (\lambda^2 + \lambda + 7)(v) = 0$$
And finally we see that eigenvalues are:
$$\lambda_{1, 2} = \dfrac{-1 \pm 3i\sqrt{3}}{2} $$
But is it usefull that they are complex? And more generally, when there exists $p \times p $ matrix $A$ whiche is ''zero'' of
$$ Q(x) = x^k + a_{k -1}x^{k-1} + \ldots + a_0$$
By this i mean the following equation
$$ A^k + a_{k-1}A^{k-1}+ \ldots + a_0I = 0$$
What conditions do we need on $p$, and coeffitients of polynomial?

Comment: For the case $k = p$, we don't need any conditions on the coefficients, in view of the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there was such a matrix $\;A\;$ then the polynomial $\;x^2+x+7\;$ is its minimal polynomial, as this is an irreducible quadratic. This means that all the matrix's eigenvalues are among the roots of this polynomial, which is impossible as any real polynomial of odd degree has a real root...can you now complete the argument and prove the impossibility of existence of such a real $\;3\times3\;$ matrix?

Comment: Odd degree?This polynomial is even degree, or i missunderstood about which polynomial you said? I have found the eigenvalues, they are 2 comples conjugated numbers, and since it's $3 \times 3 $ matrix it's characteristic polynomial $ = det(A - \lambda I)$ is odd degree and has 2 complex conjugated roots and one real root, or equivalently it is $(x-a)(x+b^2)$ for $a, b $ real.

Comment: @NeoFanatic You clearly wrote it is a $\;3\times 3\;$ matrix, which makes it of odd degree...! And all the rest is *exactly* what the answer implies...

Comment: Thank you very much!It seems, that i understood! If such matrix $A \in Mat_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ exists, then all her eigenvalues are $\dfrac{-1 \pm 3i\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and since it's real $3 \times 3$ matrix her characteristic polynomial $det(A- \lambda I)$ has 1 real root, because it's odd degree, and this real root should be an eigenvalue of this matrix, but it's not complex number, contradiction.

Comment: Exactly that, @NeoFanatic . Nice!